# Cannot autowire vendor service: has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, yaml, autowired

In my Symfony 6 app, I am trying to use dependency injection within my `service.yaml` file to bind some arguments but getting an error:

> Cannot autowire service "Microsoft\BingAds\Auth\ServiceClient": argument "$serviceClientType" of method "__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly.

And in the YAML file:

```
Microsoft\BingAds\Auth\ServiceClient:
    autowire: true
```

The problem with it is that it is a part of the vendor library package so I can not edit it.

Maybe it is not necessary but the `ServiceClient` class constructor looks something like this:

```
public function __construct($serviceClientType, $authorizationData, $apiEnvironment, $options = array())
    {
        ...
    }
```

Can someone help with how to surpass this error?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what value you are gonna pass to the serviceclient constructor ?

Comment: Just to clarify, autowire has not yet achieved sentience.  That is not scheduled till Symfony 8.  Until then it needs some hints such as type hints to do it's job.  So it simply cannot handle this particular class.  You need to manually wire it per the answer below.  You might also want to see if there are any Symfony Bing Ads bundles out there.  Defining services are a big part of bundles.  Might save you some work or give you an example.

Comment: Made me laugh, people could expect some chatgpt-esque services autowiring in Symfony 8 with your answer

Comment: Symfony 8 might be a bit optimistic but it won't be long before you can pass an app to an AI and get back an optimized container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says you that autowiring doesn't work because arguments are not type-hinted. So set it explicitly in `service.yaml`:

```yaml
Microsoft\BingAds\Auth\ServiceClient:
    arguments:
        $serviceClientType: YOUR_VALUE_HERE
        $authorizationData: YOUR_VALUE_HERE
        $apiEnvironment: YOUR_VALUE_HERE
```